# unresolved socket address

Tags: java

Buenas, tengo realizada una clase que realiza un conexión http a una url para descargarse un archivo excell a un directorio local. Dicha clase en un método main funciona bien pero en el momento que traslado dicha clase a un método en SAP Netweaver Developer Studio me está devolviendo el siguiente error. Este es mi código del método que descarga el archivo Excell:

```
File dir = new File(folderName);
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                if (!dir.mkdir()) {
                    return salida;
                }
            }
            File f = new File (folderName + "/" + fileName);
            //Creamos el proxy para poder conectarnos a la URL
            Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("10.65.4.1", 8080));

            String ruta = rutaFocus + fileName + descarga;

            URL url = new URL(ruta);
            HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);

            uc.connect();
            int b = 0;
            while (b != -1) {
                b = in.read();
                if (b != -1) {
                    out.write(b);
                }
            }
            out.close();
            in.close();
```

Pero me devuelve el error en la línea

```
 HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy)
```

dando como error:

> org.w3c.www.protocol.http.HttpException: Connect timed out.

Alguien podría darme alguna explicación o el porque me devuelve el error. Gracias

Comment: Me suena más problema de SAP Netweaver que de Java, investiga si existe algúna manera de configurar el proxy (desde la interfaz de SAP), además si el servidor donde lo tengas tiene abierto el puerto 8080 para la salida.

Comment: Si estás en lo cierto es problema de SAP Netweaver de Java al no tener acceso al exterior, gracias por la información. Saludos

Comment: Puedes poner la respuesta a tu pregunta como lo solucionaste, para que se quede en un futuro.